# scratchbox1 compile glib - zlib header not found

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I used scratchbox1 to compile glib-2.38.1 for armv7 architecture, but when I execute `./configure`, I got an error:

> error: Working zlib library and headers not found

I don't know how to get zlib header in scratchbox1
I tried:

> fakeroot apt-get install zlib1g-dev

I still got an error:

> /scratchbox/tools/bin/fakeroot: line 185: apt-get: command not found

More information:

- My PC is running ubuntu 12.04 LST
- I installed scratchbox1 following the guide at [Installing Scratchbox](http://felipec.wordpress.com/2009/06/07/installing-scratchbox-1-and-2-for-arm-cross-compilation/)

Comment: I have solved this problem by installed extra package: scratchbox-devkit-debian-squeeze

Comment: It's too complicated, so I decide to switch to scratchbox2